# How do I use the CreateFilter method in directshow.net?

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

Would someone just show me an example of how this createfilter method in directshow should work?

I see that a string is passed as a parameter but I don't understand what that string exactly is. I only understand the GUID part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `CreateFilter` method and even identifier in latest DirectShow.NET 2.1.

There are `CreateFilter` methods in a couple of sample projects and they do the action explained in comment right there.

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerates all filters of the selected category and returns the IBaseFilter for the 
/// filter described in friendlyname
/// </summary>
/// <param name="category">Category of the filter</param>
/// <param name="friendlyname">Friendly name of the filter</param>
/// <returns>IBaseFilter for the device</returns>
private IBaseFilter CreateFilter(Guid category, string friendlyname)
{
```

Comment: Thanks,however, my questions was what this friendly name is and where to get it.

Comment: Look this up in the sample projects. `CreateFilter` is not anything "standard", friendly names however are. You get them by enumerating available devices/filters and each one has a friendly name. The samples give you an idea how it is done and what it is for.